# #define 'ing multiple macros in one line

Tags: c++, macros

In C++, we can use `#define` to define a macro like `#define PI 3.14` and then use `PI` all throughout the code to represent `3.14`.

My question is : Can we `#define` multiple macros in one line so that I don't need to write n lines to define n macros.

I actually want to do this to represent array elements by alternate names (letters actually) as evident by the code snippet below.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define R dig[0]
#define E dig[1]
#define D dig[2]
#define B dig[3]
#define L dig[4]
#define U dig[5]
#define Y dig[6]
#define O dig[7]
#define W dig[8]
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int dig[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // R,E,D,B,L,U,Y,O,W
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a method to `#define` all those macros in one line so that I don't have to write multiple lines like in the above code snippet? Thanks.

Comment: No. But you can use `enum`.

Comment: This is a bad idea. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @M.M, a cryptarithm. I already solved it, just need to know if I can shorten the code by using an alternative to using multiple `#define`s.

Comment: I mean, this technique is not actually useful; if your code uses this then your code could be greatly improved. But based on your post we don't know what your code looks like.

Comment: @M.M, if viewing the full source code helps, [here](http://ideone.com/x5MUjP) it is.

Comment: Just put that code in the question, it's not too big

Comment: @M.M, I'd prefer not to, to be honest. What do you suggest I should do for my problem, i.e., alternative to multiple `#define`'s. Do note that I'm a hobbyist coder, not a professional programmer. I'm actually a mathematics undergraduate, so I'm not that experienced with coding.

Comment: disliking macros is not a warrant to downvote. this is a perfectly valid thing to do, although ideally you should undef your temporary macros after you're done using them. That said, it's unfortunate C preprocessor is weaker then VBScript in variable definitions(VBScript has a colon to break statements up). Your style is fine assuming you anticipate referring to those specific 9 objects often and want a shorthand for a part of code; doing so can greatly simplify a part of code, but you have to undef the macros after you're done to outweigh the readability harm of not doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining one macro is bad enough.

In your comments, you wonder about an alternative method. There is one in C++ :

```
auto &R = dig[0], &E = dig[1], &D = dig[2] // etc ...
```

This isn't just one line but even one statement. Slightly more verbose, you could do

```
auto &R = dig[0]; auto &E = dig[1]; auto &D = dig[2] // etc ...
```

and it's now multiple statements on one line. (see the semicolons?)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the end of #define statement is the end of the line. So no, you can't write a few separate ones in one line. As someone mentioned, use enum here instead.

Comment: You cannot use `enum` to do the specific thing the poster is trying to do; only macros will work for that.

Comment: Right. Enum is not suitable here (at least in this form), my bad.

Comment: Oh, true. Did not notice what he really wants. So yea, that said, only macros can help here. Or you use dig[A] with enum instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in either C or C++.

Have you considered writing a program to generate repetitive code at build time?  That's an under-appreciated technique.

Comment: I tried. Couldn't think of anything, which is why I asked this on SO.

Comment: Extra preprocessing is annoying when you're using an IDE

Comment: @M.M "Get a real <s>computer</s> build tool."

Comment: one way of doing this is by using PHP to generate your C(or ASP or JSP or really any similar tool; I've heard awk can be used too but I'm not sure yet). It has benefits but just for this one automation it's not really worth it.